# How do you set a cookie from a Heroku back end to a Netlify front end?

Tags: reactjs, go, heroku, cookies, netlify

I have a Go server deployed on heroku, and a react server deployed on Netlify, and I am running into an issue where the cookie set on sign in from heroku is not being set on my browser on the netlify. I have tried setting the domain of the cookie to `netlify.app` to `millerbank.netlify.app` (name of app), to omitting the domain, none of which worked at getting the cookie to reach the browser.

When I omit the Domain, I receive this error:

```
This Set-Cookie was blocked due to user preferences
```

When I change the Domain to `netlify.app` or `millerbank.netlify.app`, I  receive this error:

```
This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute is invalid with regards to the current host URL
```

Here is the code that sets the cookie on my Go server:

```
cookie :=  &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "jwt",
        Path:     "/",
        HttpOnly: true,
        Value:    tokenString,
        Expires:  expiry,
        Secure:   true,
        Domain:   "netlify.app",
}

http.SetCookie(res, cookie)
```

Here are the CORS options:

```
newCors := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000", "https://millerbank.netlify.app"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
    }) 
    router.Use(newCors.Handler)
```

And here is the React code connecting to it:

```
try {
     await axios.post("https://better-bank-account-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/signin", data, { withCredentials: true })
     dispatch({type: actionTypes.UPDATE_USERNAME, payload: username})                
     navigate("/dashboard")     
} catch (error) {
     console.log("err:", error.response.data);

     if(error.response.data.errInvalidLogin){
           setSigninError(error.response.data.errInvalidLogin)
           setIsSigninError(true)
     }
 }
```

When running both my back end and front end on my localhost, cookies are set just fine, but making requests to my deployed back end from my deployed front end results in no cookies getting set. What other options do I have?

Comment: Specifying `netlify.app` for your cookie's Domain attribute won't work, because that domain is on the [Public Suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/).

Comment: Are you witnessing this behaviour in an Incognito window, by any chance? What about a normal window?

Comment: @jub0bs It occurs in both a normal window, and an incognito window unfortunately.